# How do appear Google maps drawing tools when button menu is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps on my site;
User can just watch route that trace other users or click "Aggiungi Itinerario" and add route himself.

My problem: google drawing tools don't appear; i think that something is wrong with js file but i don't understand what.

javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/rnkt7wtw/

```js
var el = document.getElementById('aggiungiItinerario');
el.onclick = addRouteMap;

function initialize() {
 var mapProp ={
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.026938, 12.375857),
  zoom: 7,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
 
 var map =new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemaps"),mapProp);
 

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

/*function button(){
 var control = document.createElement('div'); 
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', function() {...});
 control.index = 1;   
 googlemaps.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', button);
*/

function addRouteMap(){
 console.log("Prova");
 var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
  drawingMode: null,
     drawingControl: true,
     drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
         drawingModes: [
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,

      ]
     }
 });
 
drawingManager.setMap(mapProp);
}
```

Somebody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: I get a javascript error `Uncaught ReferenceError: mapProp is not defined`

Comment: `mapProp` is not a `google.maps.Map` object.

Comment: Edit: i seen it just now
what can i do? 
i must declare mapProp as Global?

Comment: No.  You need to declare `map` as a global (or pass it into the `addRouteMap()` function).  `mapProp` is not a `google.maps.Map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error Uncaught ReferenceError: mapProp is not defined.

`mapProp` is not a `google.maps.Map` object. You need to make your `map` variable global and use it in the `drawingManager.setMap` call.

```
var el = document.getElementById('aggiungiItinerario');
el.onclick = addRouteMap;
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapProp ={
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.026938, 12.375857),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    map =new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemaps"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function addRouteMap(){
    console.log("Prova");
    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: null,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,

            ]
        }
    });

drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yemu7bc0/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var el = document.getElementById('aggiungiItinerario');
el.onclick = addRouteMap;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.026938, 12.375857),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemaps"), mapProp);


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

/*function button(){
 var control = document.createElement('div'); 
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', function() {...});
 control.index = 1;   
 googlemaps.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', button);
*/

function addRouteMap() {
  console.log("Prova");
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: null,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,

      ]
    }
  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
.l-box {
  padding: 1em;
  border-style: solid;
}
#googlemaps {
  height: 80vh;
}
.pure-g {
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places,drawing"></script>
<div class="pure-g">

  <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
    <a href="#" class="pure-menu-heading pure-menu-link">###</a>

    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">###</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">###</a>
      </li>
      <li id="aggiungiItinerario" class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Aggiungi Itinerario</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>




  <div id="googlemaps" class="pure-u-1">

    <div class="l-box">

      <!--<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eleifend eu dolor nec ultrices. In auctor aliquam nisi, vitae tincidunt magna blandit maximus. Donec dapibus, lectus sed tincidunt auctor, metus ligula porttitor eros, et dignissim nunc ante vitae ligula. Phasellus fermentum magna orci, in pharetra ipsum egestas et. Sed gravida venenatis pellentesque. Suspendisse metus quam, faucibus ac vehicula ac, hendrerit sit amet ligula. Phasellus eget sagittis velit.
    </p> -->
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">
    <div class="l-box">
      <p>Suspendisse venenatis faucibus sem, ut porttitor nisi dictum eget. Aliquam mollis consectetur lobortis. Sed ultrices neque a neque vulputate, eu vestibulum libero sagittis. Phasellus consequat sollicitudin ligula vel laoreet. Integer maximus nisi
        quis diam congue pulvinar. Suspendisse maximus augue erat, non ultricies tortor commodo ac. Curabitur quis turpis commodo erat placerat feugiat. Phasellus pharetra sed purus ac eleifend.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">
    <div class="l-box">
      <p>Integer erat nibh, ullamcorper vitae blandit vulputate, sagittis sed nulla. Mauris pulvinar tristique lorem at accumsan. Phasellus id nisl metus. Ut sed sapien vel urna fringilla euismod. Ut varius laoreet eros, et bibendum urna tristique eu. Donec
        scelerisque dapibus nulla id malesuada. Praesent tempus at elit nec facilisis. Nam eget nisl volutpat, aliquam massa sit amet, scelerisque tellus. Aliquam quis justo tempor, scelerisque augue id, mollis est. Integer et massa ullamcorper, sollicitudin
        nibh vitae, eleifend sem. Nulla leo ligula, ultrices a vehicula quis, maximus vitae mi. Praesent semper, nulla et convallis fringilla, neque ipsum malesuada nulla, nec efficitur enim magna vel eros. Quisque in sem sed dui maximus interdum. In
        ac odio purus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this  error is so stupid; i don't know how i can't see it before.

I have another question, can i write here or i must open other topic?

technically how can i storage user route? with dbms? i don't see nothing about that on google api documentation

Comment: Another question should be asked in another question.